# How can I figure out my Python code with Kivy and Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pi-4, rpi.gpio

I try to add actionbar to all screenmanagers in Kivy 2.1.0. I found some solution to my problem but I added some more features like GPIO pinout from Raspberry Pi. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482899/how-to-add-an-action-bar-in-kivy-using-screenmanager-widget) is a solution without gpio.

I try to code with BoxLayout in the main.py but when I click the button, nothing happens. Has the code any logical problem? Could you check it, please?

Note: When I code without Boxlayout, that works fine. When I add Boxlayout in `.kv` file, programm does not work.

Here main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

up=4
down=17
GPIO.setwarnings(False)                                         
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                                          # BCM: use the gpio numbers, BOARD :use physical pin numbering

pulling=GPIO.PUD_UP                                             
GPIO.setup(up,      GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=pulling)              
GPIO.setup(down,    GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=pulling)                 

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BoxTest(BoxLayout):
    
    def buttonUp(self, channel):
        print('2. message on screen')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.buttonUp)
        
    def buttonDown(self, channel):
        print('2. message on screen')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.buttonDown)

    class BoxTest:

        def __init__(self):
            self.state = BoxTest.PageHome(self)

        def buttonUp(self,dt):                                          
            self.state = self.state.buttonUp(self) 

        def buttonDown(self,dt):                                         
            self.state = self.state.buttonDown(self) 

        class State:
            def __init__(self, dt):
                pass

        class PageHome(State):        
            def buttonUp(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenUp('second')
                return BoxTest.PageSecond(self)
            def buttonDown(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenDown('first')
                return BoxTest.PageFirst(self)

        class PageFirst(State):
            def buttonUp(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenUp('welcome')
                return BoxTest.PageHome(self)
            def buttonDown(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenDown('second')
                return BoxTest.PageSecond(self)
        
        class PageSecond(State):
            def buttonUp(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenUp('first')
                return BoxTest.PageFirst(self)
            def buttonDown(self, dt):
                App.get_running_app().screenDown('welcome')
                return BoxTest.PageHome(self)

Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class TestApp(App):
    boxtest= BoxTest() 
    
    def screenUp(self, screenName):                                                            
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
        self.manager.current = screenName

    def screenDown(self, screenName):                                                           
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
        self.manager.current = screenName

    def buttonUp(self, channel):
        print('1. message on screen')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.boxtest.buttonUp)
        
    def buttonDown(self, channel):
        print('1. message on screen')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.boxtest.buttonDown)

    def build(self):                                                                       
        self.manager = ScreenManager()
        self.boxtest = BoxTest()

        GPIO.add_event_detect(up,           GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.buttonUp,       bouncetime=1)                               # start button definition
        GPIO.add_event_detect(down,         GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.buttonDown,     bouncetime=1)                               # stop button definition

        return self.boxtest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and here main.kv

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import sp kivy.metrics.sp
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp

<BoxTest>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .7, .5, .2, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        WelcomeScreen:
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:

    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome Screen'
        font_size: sp(50)

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    Label:
        text: 'First Screen'
        font_size: sp(50)

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Second Screen'
            font_size: 50

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Boxlayout 1'
                font_size: 30
            Button:
                text: 'Boxlayout 2'
                font_size: 30

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    pos: (0,0)
    size_hint_y:0.1
    size: root.width , 50
    background_color: (.5,.5,.5,.5)
    ActionView:
        id:av
        ActionPrevious:
            with_previous: False
            app_icon: ''   # Set the Icon to an empty String  
        
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Number One'
            size_hint_x: 1
            font_size: 25
            color: (0,0,1,1)

        ActionButton:
            text: 'Number Two'
            font_size: 25
            color: (0,1,0,1)
            size_hint_x: 1

        ActionButton:
            #   id: micro_text
            text: 'Number Three'
            font_size: 25
            color: (1,0,0,1)
            size_hint_x: 1
```

If any help, would be nice. Thank you for helping.

Comment: thank you for the comment. Actually I called buttonUp in main class and BoxTest class. But why nothing happening, couldn't find it. Normally, when click the buttons up and down, welcome screen should swipes to first screen or second screen. I think, the problem is with the logic in the code.

Comment: I would suggest breaking down your code into small steps. When I last built an interaction window in Java, I made a new test for each component. Then I added data to the component. I've been programming for over 35 years, and I still try to be methodical.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would like to try a new thing like boxlayout in my code. Without boxlayout, that works fine and code lines doubled. Somehow, when I add boxlayout, program does not work.